# What is function of _ShowAndroidToastMessage() in ARCore?

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I found this method while reading script of HelloARController in HelloAR, but I couldn't understand this function: `private void _ShowAndroidToastMessage(string message))`.

Can someone explain this function for me?

```
/// <summary>
/// Show an Android toast message.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">Message string to show in the toast.</param>
private void _ShowAndroidToastMessage(string message)
{
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    if (unityActivity != null)
    {
        AndroidJavaClass toastClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
        unityActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
        {
            AndroidJavaObject toastObject = toastClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", unityActivity,
                message, 0);
            toastObject.Call("show");
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Toasts` in Android are used to show `Notification` within an `Activity`. You may be knowing what alert messages are in HTML. Using javaScript `alert()` function we can `Alert` the user about something using a popup message, the user sees the message and clicks the **`OK`** button to dismiss the dialog.

`Toast` messages in Android Programming are similar but they are `terminated`/`dismissed` by itself (we do not have any buttons). We need to set a time period for which the message has to be displayed, when the time is reached the message fades away, it is usually shown at the bottom of the `Activity` page.

> `_ShowAndroidToastMessage()` method is one of the varieties for Toast messaging.

Here's one more simple example of Toast:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View toastView = toast.getView();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                                     "This is a Toast message!", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct answer Thx

Answer (score 0):

It just show a toast message that is supported by Android.
Refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.